# External change to database not propagating to entity spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working on some rest apis which are being developed in spring boot and data jpa.
The database which is an oracle backed is *supposed to be modified out side of the jpa*.
The problem I am having is the change made to the database out side the jpa is not propagating to the entities.
I tired doing below but none worked for me.

Clearing all cache

```
for (String name : cacheManager.getCacheNames()) {
    System.out.println(name);
    cacheManager.getCache(name).clear();
}
```

Clearing session cache

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.clear();
```

Refreshing entity from the entity manager

```
entityManager.refresh(entity);
```

Evicting entity manager cache

```
Cache cache = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache();
cache.evictAll();
```

Disabling cache in properties

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

Adding cachable false to entities

```
@Cacheable(false)
```

I tried literally everything and looking on all the possible solution from the google search and so. I may be making some mistake but coming from the django and python experience I thought it would be simple to disable caching or anything that prevents loading entities from the database directly but seems like its not so simple.

Honestly have spent 2 night solving this but nothing worked for me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elborate your question more? You mentioned 
"The database which is an oracle backed is supposed to be modified out side of the jpa" :- What are you trying to do here, what is that you are trying to modify.

"change made to the database out side the jpa is not propagating to the entities" :- Are you saying that your are executing the DML on your entities from another application but when you pull the data in your boot app via jpa you are not seeing it?

Comment: Some entries are being made through other program to the table mapped as entity in jpa

Comment: That other program will initiate its own transaction and commit to the entity. When they do can you connect to your dB via sql editor and query the table to see the updated rows? If yes then a simple Jpa repository method to pull the data out in your boot app should work as well. Also consider writing native jpa query and see if that helps.

Comment: I am able to see the changes made into the database by other program. 
I am just wondering why the jpa cannot bring those changes into the entities.
Is there any jpa way of getting those changes into the entities?

Comment: Try making your services interacting with entites transaction. There are different catgories your can choose but for this just make is always required for example :-


@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW) 

Another example ::

@ Component
@ Transactional
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @ Autowired
    ItemRepository repository;

    @ Override

Comment: Does the other application actually issue a commit? What happens if you restart your application? Do you see the changes then? If yes check if hibernate actually issues the expected sql during your calls.

Comment: I am able to figure it out, the other program was not issuing the commit and hence the changes were being seen in the database but probably were being rolled back after the program restart, which I was thinking a merge issue with jap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? It should work.

```
Session  session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.refresh(entity);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your database transaction isolation levels ? It can create isolation between transactions so you can't access the updated data.